# Detect app installation status in iPhone using php (APNS) ?

Tags: php, iphone

When i try to send push notifications from the server, the devices are not receiving that. I have tried to sort out that issue and concluded that most of the pushnotifications tokens registered in the devices are not active now (apps already removed from device). How can i identify which devices are still using the app so that i can remove the inactive devices from the server list?

Comment: After lot of Googling i find the solution to solve the issue...:)          https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/mo-ios-push/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **TestFlight SDK**.

By using the SDK you are able to track user activities for your app **On Air**, that is remotely analyse the app in the device (Supported by IOS & Android)

Reference Link:

http://testflightapp.com/sdk

Comment: After lot of Googling i find the solution to solve the issue...:)          https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/mo-ios-push/